# In Dropwizard's db migration wrapper, is it possible to migrate based on contexts?

Tags: java, migration, liquibase, dropwizard

With `liquibase` there is the feature to specify contexts on your change sets.  For xml its in a tag like `context=test` (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html). 
 The idea with contexts being, you could have migration that only get applied when you specify certain contexts (like load this test data only when running in `qa` or `test` contexts).

I can't seem to find a way within Dropwizard's `db migrate` to utilize this functionality.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer... No, after digging in I've found that dropwizard only exposes a limited subset the liquibase functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible!

Use `-i` or `--include` to specify which contexts to use

Example:

```
java -jar app.jar db migrate -i myContext config.yml
```